# How to create a date field in QGIS shapefile

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, date

When I create a new shapefile in QGIS, I'm presented with the "New Vector Layer" window, where I specify the Shapefile type (Point/Line/Polygon) and am then able to create attribute fields.

I'm only able to select the field type as Text/Integer/Decimal - how do I go about creating a date field type?

Answer (score 5):

The way I have done this is as follows:

```
 - Add a column to your attribute table (ie: Date, Text, 10 characters)
 - Open the layer properties window and navigate to the Fields tab
 - On the Date line under the Edit widget, change it from Line edit to Calender
 - To add a date to the attribute, double click the Date field record in the attribute table and click on the ... button
 - Choose the appropriate date![QGIS Date Attributes][1]
```

Comment: I tried this when the table is in a MSSQL database. I get an error message that says that QGIS could not commit the changes because the number of fields is not correct. Is this a permissions 'thing' with SQL databases?

Comment: On further inspection and research, after closing my QGIS project and opening again, the new attribute column is there.